Split pdf pages workflow with celery
I have the following use case using Celery and Flask.
A user uploads a PDF file. I want a worker to count the number of pages, n workers to split each page in a separate PDF file in parallel and then one worker to generate a report.
                    +----------------+                    
                    |                |                    
                    | Count pages    |                    
                    |                |                    
                    +--------|-------+                    
                             |                            
         |-------------------|-------------------|        
         |                   |                   |        
+--------|-------+  +--------|-------+  +--------|-------+
|                |  |                |  |                |
| Split page 1   |  | Split page 2   |  | Split page 3   |
|                |  |                |  |                |
+----------------+  +----------------+  +----------------+
         |                   |                   |        
         |                   |                   |        
         -----------------------------------------        
                             |                            
                    +----------------+                    
                    |                |                    
                    | Generate report|                    
                    |                |                    
                    +----------------+                    

As you can see, count_pages result should create n split_page tasks. But at the same time, count page shouldn't block the upload endpoint so it can't be called synchronously.
So far I tried to play with chord, group and chain but I did not find a way to trigger n split_page tasks asynchronously after count_page has finished.

@KJ It doesn't seems your solution is using celery

PDF splitting was an example, my issue is about Celery workflows orchestration - not about splitting the document itself or about long tasks timeout (the post you mentionned talks about +12 hours long tasks, which is obviously not my case).
Please stop posting irrelevant comments.
